# how to reset the zsh command in terminal

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPnId.png)How to reset the zsh

Terminal not working properly.if I put any command
zsh: command not found: sudo message showing like this
and how to install zsh and zshrc.source and nano file are not installed in zsh.it always showing zsh: comment not found

Comment: Have you tried `rm .zshrc`?

Comment: zsh: command not found: rm getting like this

Comment: Can you try this PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
export PATH and this for reseting zsh exec /bin/zsh?